# Cant run maven project. Try running with '--enable-preview'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, preview

i just cant get my maven spring boot project to run... i think i have tried everything there is on the internet. I am desperate at this point.

here is the output when i try to run the project:

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1$ mvn -e org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:run
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< net.candidatis:tierone >-----------------------
[INFO] Building tierone 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ tierone >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ tierone ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ tierone ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 59 source files to /var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ tierone ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tierone ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ tierone <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) @ tierone ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.candidatis.tierone.TieroneApplication
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for net/candidatis/tierone/TieroneApplication (class file version 59.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.449 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-20T11:35:12+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) on project tierone: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) on project tierone: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml file

```
<properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>

.
.
.
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>15</release> <!-- <release>13/14/15</release> -->
                <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have added the maven environmental variable MAVEN_OPTS="--enable-preview" to PATH.

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1$ echo $MAVEN_OPTS
--enable-preview
```

I have created

I have created a jvm.config file inside my projects .mvn subfolder

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1/.mvn$ cat jvm.config 
--enable-preview
```

Maven uses Java 15

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-42-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

My JAVA_HOME variable pointing to that very library

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
```

All in my PATH:

```
olw@candidatis:/var/www/git/miw/tiger/TigerT1$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin/java:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

All solutions that i am finding are only about what i have already done.

Can anybody help me ?

Regards...

Comment: Is there a good reason why not using JDK16 instead ? JDK15 is EoL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the reason Maven's `jvm.config` does not work is because those arguments apply to the JVM which runs Maven, but Spring Boot's `run` goal is forking a new JVM process without those arguments.

You can either disable forking using the `fork` config property, so your app runs in the same JVM as Maven did, or specify `jvmArguments` for the forked process.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            ...
        </excludes>
        <fork>false</fork><!-- jvmArguments OR this, but not both -->
        <jvmArguments>--enable-preview</jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Documentation for those 2 properties, as well others which might be useful, is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)